# Russell's paradox from Cantor's

Tags: logic, paradoxes

I learnt how Russell's paradox can be derived from Cantor's theorem [here](https://www.quora.com/Wikipedia-describes-Russells-paradox-as-an-example-of-a-diagonal-argument-along-the-lines-of-the-one-Cantor-made-in-his-proof-of-the-existence-of-uncountable-infinite-sets-Why-is-Russells-paradox-a-diagonal-argument/answer/Hans-Hyttel?srid=uajIN), but also from S C Kleene's Introduction to Metamathematics, page 38.

> In his book, Kleene says that if $M$ is set of all sets, then $\mathcal P(M)=M$ but since this implies $\mathcal P(M)$ has same cardinality as $M$, so there exists a subset $T$ of $M$ which is not element of power set $\mathcal P(M)$. This $T$ is desired set for Russell's paradox, i.e., it is the set of all sets which are not members of themselves.

I can't understand how $T$ is desired set for Russell's paradox. Also, how is Kleene's argument similar to the quora answer?

Comment: Does Kleene really write "this ${\cal T}$ is desired set for Russell's paradox"? I would have expected his English to be much better than that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cantor's theorem shows that for any set $X$ and any function $f:X\to \mathcal{P}(X)$, there is some subset $T\subseteq X$ that is not in the image of $f$.  Specifically, $T=\{x\in X:x\not\in f(x)\}$.  Kleene is saying that if you apply this theorem to the identity function $f:M\to\mathcal{P}(M)$, the counterexample $T$ you get is exactly Russell's set.  Indeed, this is immediate from the definition of $T$ given above.  The Quora answer is just carrying out the diagonal proof that $T$ is not in the image of $f$ in this particular example.

Comment: I will be really obliged if you can answer me why $M\subset \mathcal P(M)$ when $M$ is set of all the sets. I asked this question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860423/how-is-a-set-subset-of-its-power-set), but could not get satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Silent Let $x\in M$; you'd like to prove that $x\subset M$. If $y\in x$, then $y\in M$ (because *everything* belongs to $M$ by assumption); thus $x\subset M$ as required.

Comment: @egreg, thank you so much!!